# How to transfer the App with the data(obb) from Nexus 5 to Emulator?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, apk

Device: Nexus 5 (d821) with Android version: 6.0.1 (no root!)

Androind Emulator on Windows 10: Nox App Player emulator

On the Nexus 5 is an App with data. App is a game from the market that does not support authorization, that is, game account data store on the device.

How do I transfer the App together with the data in the emulator?

I can not find a way to root Nexus without erasing data.

Without a root, I can not make the transfer apk + obb.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps

1. run following command while connected to device

   **adb backup -noapk com.XXX.XXX  ( Your App Package Name )**
2. This will prompt for backup password on phone ( keep it blank ) and follow instructions on phone
3. Once backup is done this will create backup.ab at adb location
4. Download Tool https://github.com/nelenkov/android-backup-extractor
5. Run command 
   **java.exe -jar abe.jar unpack backup.ab test.tar ""**

test.tar will contain all your required app data. Use it as per your requirement.

Comment: Amod, You are awesome! After all steps I have next folders: db (google_analytics_v4.db, google_analytics_v4.db-journal) | ef (config.dat, Cookies, HTTPCache, Library, playerCollection.dat, playerData.dat, playerGamelog.dat, Unity) | f (AppEventsLogger.persistedevents, gaClientId) | sp (com.facebook.internal.preferences.APP_SETTINGS.xml,  ...more .xml files). Where should I drop these files correctly in the emulator (root enable)?

Comment: 1. Install basic app to simulator . 2. try running adb restore backup.ab ( Make sure only simulator is connected while running this).

Comment: if above steps doesn't work 1. Install basic app on simulator 2. use any explorer to access data/data/com.XXX.XXX folder and copy only app specific data files ( no need to copy facebook, other readonly xml files )

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work. Tried it differently. I put the game from the market, from apk. Restored from backup, copied through the file manager ... Each attempt I reset virtual device. Feeling like playing the first time it checks something on the emulator (some id) and creates a new playerXXXX :(

Comment: I follow same steps and gets my database and temporary files updated but never tried on 6.0.1.. will try when i get chance.. you can try to directly install the backup file using Droid Explorer https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/102631/restore-droid-explorer-backup